# How to Open the popup ads in new tab insted of new window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having small of daily visitor 400 per-day. I planed to create the popup ads first I created the popup ads  to open in new window . It was quit irritating the visitors .

My New window popup code

```
var firstClick = true;
document.body.onclick = function() {
    if (firstClick) {
        window.open('popup creating website', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
        window.open('popup creating second website', 'poppage2', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 200, top = 10');
        firstClick = false;
    }
}
```

> what i planed to get is first click on the web page to open the new tab .

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: PS if I had the choice between ads in popups or tabs and death wasn't an option I would rather popups vs clogging up all of my tabs.

Comment: @Marty Meh. I'd just block them.

Comment: @Marty In that page they mention like If we click on the "button or name" then only the new tab will open..  My question is based on the any where in the page first click to open a new tab . I tried nothing is working..

Answer (score -2):

You can use target attribute to open in new tab

> Example

```
<a href="#" target="blank">click here</a>
```

Comment: Because a) you meant `_blank` not `blank` and b) the OP needs a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Because it depends upon browser settings.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use "target=_blank" in your hyperlink

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
     $('#newtab').click(function() {   
     $(this).target = "_blank";
     window.open($(this).prop('href'));   
     return false; 
     });
  });​

<a href="link" id="newtab" >new tab</a>
```

Comment: May i know the reason of down vote?helps me in answering other questions.

Comment: You've updated the `target` attribute of an element that hasn't been referenced in the question anywhere, then used `window.open` with the `href` attribute of the same element, making your `target` value irrelevant anyway.